# Unable to change email address of admin on localhost

Tags: users, email, email-verification

If I try to change my email address, it will say it has sent a confirmation email to the new email address.  But, I do not see any email request to that email.

Is there a way to troubleshoot this or understand the error?

Comment: How is your site set up to send mail? Is it using a specific SMTP server? Or just the local sendmail on the machine that's hosting the site? Is that set up correctly - can you send email from anything else on the machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can also change your email address from your database with below steps:

1. Log into the database.
2. Locate the `wp_options` table.
3. Near the top locate the `admin_email` option : https://prnt.sc/waaxez
4. Edit the `option_value` field with the new email. This can be done either inline, or by editing depending on your version of phpMyAdmin
5. Save your work if it wasn’t auto-saved

Answer (score 1):

The problem is *most likely* that your localhost environment is not set up to actually send email.  That's not a WordPress issue, and so it is out-of-scope for this site. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/ or https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ and ask about setting up a localhost development environment that can send email.

The simple workaround is to change the `admin_email` value in the `wp_options` table. @ZealousWeb already described that so I won't repeat it here.

Another simple possibility is to use an email logger plugin. Then when the confirmation email is generated, you can actually access its content from WP, allowing you to copy the confirmation link you need.

Comment: Another option is to set up a third-party mail send API e.g. mailgun, sendgrid, postmark, Amazon SES etc. to actually send the email - they'll all have WordPress plugins and free account tiers for low volumes. That's probably easier than setting up a local sendmail, if you have your own domain to send from.